# Interpretation and modification of maxSizeInMegabytes for ServiceBus Topic

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

I'm trying to reconcile the various ways the "maxSizeInMegabytes" property is interpreted in ARM and the portal. I create a partitioned, standard ServiceBus Topic with my ARM template and the property:

```
    "maxSizeInMegabytes": "1024",
```

When I view the topics list in the portal, I see 16GB (perhaps multiplied out b/c of partitioning?)

[image]

When I drill into the topic defintion, I then see

[image]

the options in the list vary from 1 to 5GB, but none is selected.

Finally, when I view the resource (resources.azure.com), I see:

[image]

So, are you supposed to enter the unpartitioned size when creating the resource, and then you get the total partitioned sized back? Clearly the portal UI is also confused, since it can't display the value in the dropdown.

Comment: ASB section of the portal is such a [mess](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Aportal). I suggest you raise this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning#enable-partitioning), we can find: ***In the Standard messaging tier, you can create Service Bus queues and topics in 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 GB sizes (the default is 1 GB). With partitioning enabled, Service Bus creates 16 copies (16 partitions) of the entity for each GB you specify.***

You create a partitioned, standard ServiceBus Topic, so you see the maxSize is 16GB (1GB * 16). If partitioning is **not** enabled when you create queue/topic, the correct option (value) will be selected in **Maximum size** drop down.

[image]

[image]

Besides, Sean Feldman has opened [an issue: Portal issue - Queue size](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/18), you can track updates. And if possible, you can report a bug on Azure portal.

[image]